# For a ring map $f:A\to B$, closure of image of $V(J)$ under associated map on Spec is $V(f^{-1}(J))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f:A \to B$ be a (commutative unitary) ring homomorphism. Let $X:=\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $Y:=\operatorname{Spec} B$, and call $f^*$ the induced function $Y\to X$. Show that, for any ideal $J\subseteq B$, one has $$\overline{f^*(V(J))}=V(f^{-1}(J)).$$

Now, it's clear that $V(f^{-1}(J))$ is a closed set containing $f^*(V(J))$: in fact suppose that a prime $p\in X$ is equal to  $f^{-1} (q)$ for some $q\in V(J)$. Since $J\subseteq q$, also $f^{-1}(J)\subseteq p$. This proves that $\overline{f^*(V(J))}\subseteq V(f^{-1}(J))$.

For the other inclusion, I thought to take a closed set $V(I)$, for an ideal $I\subseteq A$, such that $f^*(V(J))\subseteq V(I)$, and prove that $V(f^{-1}(J))\subseteq V(I)$. However I don't see how to proceed here, do you have any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a point $x\in X$ which is not in the closure of $f^*(V(J))$. This means that we can find some $a\in A$ which vanishes on $f^*(V(J))$ but not on $x$. Saying $a$ vanishes on $f^*(V(J))$ means $a\in f^{-1}(J)$, though, so this shows that $x\notin V(f^{-1}(J))$.

Comment: There is something that I don't understand; did you use that if $a\in A$ belongs to all the primes in a subset $S\subseteq X$, then $a$ must be also in all primes in $\bar S$?

Comment: Sure, you could also say "we can find some $a\in A$ which vanishes on $\overline{f^*(V(J))}$ but not on $x$".

Comment: Sorry if I'm slow but there is another passage unclear: $a$ vanishes on $f^*(V(J))$ means that for every prime $q\supseteq J$, one has $a\in f^{-1}(q)$. How do I deduce that $a\in f^{-1}(J)$?

Comment: First, assume $J=\sqrt{J}$ since we only care about set-theoretic stuff here. Next, observe that $f(a)\in q$ for all primes $q\supset J$, so since $J=\sqrt{J}$, $f(a)\in J$. Done.